# A generalization of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem?

Tags: general-topology

In the setting of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem, is it true that for any distance $d$ there exist two points $A$ and $B$ with distance $d$, such that $f(A)=f(B)$? (Two antipodal points having the maximal distance).

Comment: You should make your question more precise. As it is, it is understandable for people who know the context. But in my opinion a question  should be understandable for all readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remark:**  As pointed out by Thomas Anton, the arguments below do not make sense: $f(u(t))$ is an element of $\mathbb R^n$, not an element of $S^n$. Thus $B = f(u(t_r)) \notin S^n$. And even if $B$ were in $S^n$, there is no reason to expect that $f(A) = f(B)$.

I tried to delete my answer, but this is impossible for accepted answers.

Here is the original answer:

Yes. The Borsuk-Ulam theorem states that for any continuous map $f : S^n \to \mathbb R^n$ there exists $x \in S^n$ such that $f(x) = f(-x)$. The points $x, y = -x$ have the distance $\lVert y - x  \rVert = 2$. Now let $u : [0,1] \to S^n$ be any path from $x$ to $y$. The function $\phi : [0,1] \to \mathbb R, \phi(t) = \lVert f(u(t)) - x \rVert$, is continuous and satisfies $\phi(0) = 0, \phi(1) = 2$. By the intermediate value theorem for each $r \in [0,2]$ there exists $t_r \in [0,1]$ such that $\phi(t_r) = r$. Now take $A = x, B = f(u(t_r))$.

By the way, this proof works for any metric $d$ on $S^n$ which generates the standard topology.

Comment: Very late, but this makes no sense. Just a sanity check among many other problems: you can’t take an arbitrary point mapping onto the same value as its antipodal point and find a point with arbitrary distance mapping to the same value. Just consider flattening a sphere.

Comment: @ThomasAnton You are right, I made a silly mistake. Thank you for pointing this out. I shall delete my answer.

Comment: @ThomasAnton I discovered that it is impossible to delete accepted answers.

Comment: @ThomasAnton I made another update.  Anyway, your first comment should not be deleted.